# How to get access to and change bulb in a hanging lantern

Tags: light-fixture, exterior, bulb

My task today was to change the light bulbs of a hanging lantern that we have on our porch. I simply cannot determine how to get to the actual light bulbs.

[image]

I've tried turning the bottom finial, which loosens the post in the middle, but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried turning the bottom finial while holding in place the top, but I have no luck there either.  The bottom portion will just keep turning and never gets fully loose.

The glass fits too well to be opened and there is no latch. There are also no recessed or exposed bolts or screws anywhere to loosen the top or bottom.

Multiple searches and installation manuals were not able to give me the answer so I'm crowdsourcing this.

I would love it if someone would be able to help me change a light bulb...

[Other pictures of the fixure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esyVQ.jpg)

Comment: Can you unscrew that bottom knob?

Comment: Having used similar ones, the hanging hoop at the top will turn and undo the nut which is visible at the top of the last photo - this will allow the entire top of the unit to come off, as the structural load goes through the centre rod to the base (the walls have no structural loading). You will want to unhang the entire unit before you try this...

Comment: I would double-check for tiny black nuts on the top near the outer edge.  Usually two.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost guaranteed that you need to keep turning that finial (perhaps pull down on it while you are turning it, in case its threads are stripped).   Keep turning and turning.  Eventually this will allow the glassed enclosure to drop down off the aligning screws that can be seen in one of your photos.  That should completely expose the bulbs, making them easy to swap out.

Comment: "The entire lantern portion of the fixture was disengaged by **turning the bottom and holding the top**. Once the lantern became loose, the nut holding the glass roof to the lantern had to be undone and then access to the bulbs was accomplished by turning the roof a 1/8 turn." –[www.doityourself.com](http://www.doityourself.com/forum/lighting-light-fixtures-ceiling-exhaust-fans/459594-how-open-outside-light-fixture.html)