# How to change the bulbs in this hanging light fixture?

Tags: hanging, bulb

There is an UN-removable circular plastic part stacked to the glass ribs that is smaller than the diameter created by the bulbs inside.  Therefore the lantern cannot slide off over the bulbs,  Nor can I reach up from underneath.

I am about to call a contractor just to change a bulb.

What kind of lantern is this? Any ideas?

How do I change the bulbs in this fixture?

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite understanding where the "irremovable circular plastic part" is, but these screws look suspect to me https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqsVs.jpg

Comment: It appears that the finial is attached to four arm that branch up and that they have  little holes in the top of them. Can you see a screw head in those holes ? There is also i little round nub in the middle underneath ??

Comment: I changed the bulbs in one similar to that. I believe that either the finial on top unscrewed or there were knurled knobs above each of the metal ribs holding the glass. In either case be careful that once you're in the glass plates don't fall out.

Comment: See also this question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93684/how-to-get-access-to-and-change-bulb-in-a-hanging-lantern

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility.  The lantern may attach between the cover (the octagonal part at the top) and the fixture (the glass bits etc.).  See [this manual](http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/848507001331_install.pdf) for a very similar if not identical fixture.

If that's the case, then either like that manual suggests there will be a couple of "decorative" nuts hidden that attach the two, or it's possible the fixture screws into the cover itself (less likely with a squareish shape, but who knows what could be under that).  If the latter is the case, we're not talking a bell jar type screw, but one where it screws maybe a half turn from an "open" position to a "closed" position.

Decorative nuts can be hard to spot, since they're intended to be hidden, but there's likely 2 or possibly 3 - so see if there's some different thing either on opposite sides or in a triangle that might be hiding nuts.  I see something that looks like it could be a nut on the left side of the picture.

Comment: That manual is close to mine but not exact.  Mine has an extra circular plastic piece under the lid which is smaller in diameter than the bulbs.  So it sounds like i am supposed to hold the weight of the glass lantern in one hand while simultaneously unscrewing the lid, then when theglass slides down and gets stuck on The bulbs which have a very wide diameter, try and twist the top to release the plastic allowing the glass to slide all the way off?  How am I supposed to do this 8 feet in the air?  Considering breaking a glass panel so i can just change bulbs whenever.  What a horrible design.